# Hiding worksheet completely in favour of userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform and would like this to be the first thing that is shown to the user when opening the workbook, and the sheet behind this form to be hidden.

I understand the below is the code to do this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.Visible = False
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

This performs the operation successfully, but my worksheet flashes up for a second or two before it is hidden and the userform appears.
This is long enough for someone to take a screenshot or see valuable information behind the userform.

It also doesn't look very tidy!

Is there a way to alter anything within the VBA to accomplish this?

I have discovered that it is possible with batch scripts or something similar but I have no experience of this and would prefer not to add another dimension to an already complex form.

Comment: You could activate a specific blank sheet, that might be faster. But the better way would be to Activate that blank sheet in the BeforeClose and BeforeSave events, that way it'll open that sheet! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd opt for a `Workbook_BeforeClose` event that hides all of the sensitive sheets. That way your data remains hidden to people opening your file without macros enabled.

This goes in a new standard module

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

Public Sub SheetsHidden(ByRef hidden As Boolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.name <> "Home" And hidden Then 'your *safe* sheet name
            ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        Else
            ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

And then you can call it from your `ThisWorkbook` module

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    SheetsHidden True
End Sub
```

Once you have authenticated the user you can unhide the sheets with the parameter as `False`.

---

I would also recommend exploring UserForms, particularly:

```
With New UserForm1
    .Show vbModeless
    'do more with your form
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

By design, opening Excel file without Excel showing up is not possible without external script or tool.

Easier way to hide all sheets is to save the file as `.xla(m)` (or using `ThisWorkbook.IsAddin = True`)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.IsAddin = True ' True by default for .xla(m) Excel Add-In files
    Application.Visible = Workbooks.Count
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not ThisWorkbook.IsAddin Then ThisWorkbook.IsAddin = True
    If Not ThisWorkbook.Saved Then ThisWorkbook.Save
    If Workbooks.Count Then Application.Visible = True Else Application.Quit
End Sub
```

and in the form close event:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    If Workbooks.Count Then ThisWorkbook.Close True Else Application.Quit
End Sub
```